# When I'm scrolled down and click a link, the next page starts out scrolled down

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I'm sorry that I can give very little example code or details, but the truth is that it would be altogether meaningless since this is a very general case.

Whenever I'm scrolled down on a page and click a link to the next page, that page starts out scrolled down. It's **not** the case that if I'm at the bottom of the first page, that I will start out at the bottom of the next; it seems a bit random that way.

Noteworthy is probably that all these links are made with `events` that use `Router.go`, for instance:

```
Router.go('showroom', {cat: category, _id: this._id})
```

Is there a fix to this, or do I have to hack around the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix : use a global `onBeforeAction` hook to scroll back to the top of the page when changing to any route :

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function(){
  $(window).scrollTop(0);
  this.next();
});
```